# COM Runtime Breakdown in Multithreaded Server Application

Tags: multithreading, debugging, com, com-interop

We are experiencing intermittent catastrophic failures of the COM runtime in a large server application.

Here's what we have:

A server process running as a Windows service hosts numerous free-threaded COM components written in C++/ATL. Multiple client processes written in C++/MFC and .NET use these components via cross-procces COM calls (incl .NET interop) on the same machine. The OS is Windows Server 2008 Terminal Server (32-bit).
The entire software suite was developed in-house, we have the source code for all components. A tracing toolkit writes out errors and exceptions generated during operation.

What is happening:

After some random period of smooth sailing (5 days to 3 weeks) the server's COM runtime appears to fall apart with any combination of these symptoms:

- RPC_E_INVALID_HEADER (0x80010111) - "OLE received a packet with an invalid header" returned to the caller on cross-process calls to server component methods
- Calls to CoCreateInstance (CCI) fail for the CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER context
- CoInitializeEx(COINIT_MULTITHREADED) calls fail with CO_E_INIT_TLS (0x80004006)
- All in-process COM activity continues to run, CCI works for CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER.
- The overall system remains responsive, SQL Server works, no signs of problems outside of our service process.
- System resources are OK, no memory leaks, no abnormal CPU usage, no thrashing

The only remedy is to restart the broken service.

Other (related) observations:

- The number of cores on the CPU has an adverse effect - a six core Xeon box fails after roughly 5 days, smaller boxes take 3 weeks or longer.
- .NET Interop might be involved, as running a lot of calls accross interop from .NET clients to unmanaged COM server components also adversely affects the system.
- Switching on the tracing code inside the server process prolongs the working time to the next failure.

Tracing does introduce some partial synchronization and thus can hide multithreaded race condition effects. On the other hand, running on more cores with hyperthreading runs more threads in parallel and increases the failure rate.

Has anybody experienced similar behaviour or even actually come accross the RPC_E_INVALID_HEADER HRESULT? There is virtually no useful information to be found on that specific error and its potential causes.
Are there ways to peek inside the COM Runtime to obtain more useful information about COM's private resource pool usage like memory, handles, synchronization primitives? Can a process' TLS slot status be monitored (CO_E_INIT_TLS)?

Comment: CO_E_INIT_TLS means that the thread-local storage couldn't be found/allocated or is corrupt.  I'd be looking at memory corruption, which could easily cause the behavior you're looking at.  Try attaching windbg to your service & dumping the process, then use !heap -s -v to check for corrupt heaps.

Comment: We checked for memory corruption intensively. The COM runtime's internal memory pools might well be corrupted but we'd expect different errors in that case. CO_E_INIT_TLS actually is returned if there are no TLS slots left to allocate. TLS slots are a process resource and not part of dynamic memory.

Comment: The OLE TLS data is allocated from the default process heap, and if the heap allocation fails, then the runtime returns CO_E_INIT_TLS.  (It *also* returns CO_E_INIT_TLS if the TLS slot can't be allocated.)

Comment: Also, what is the failure code for `CoCreateInstance(...,CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, ...)`?

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce the problem with a test program that just creates and destroys objects in a tight loop? If so that may help you with being able to debug?

Comment: @EricBrown : Thanks for your input! CCI fails with E_OUTOFMEMORY. We have a tool that allows us to allocate TLS slots inside the server process. Even when all of them (1088) have been reserved the system continues to run. Also the error description for CO_E_INIT_TLS is "Failed to allocate COM's internal TLS structure" - which very clearly also includes corrupt memory. Thanks again for pointing this out...

Comment: @MattMcNabb : We are setting up dummy load and stress probes right now in an attempt to produce a MTBF of much less than 5 days. We're also running tests on more cores (SMP server box) than the original six to produce even more parallelism and expose a possible race condition more quickly...

Comment: CCI also allocates the TLS data, and returns E_OUTOFMEMORY if the TLS allocation fails.  There could be other paths that return E_OUTOFMEMORY (proxy load failure, for instance), but that's the obvious path.

Answer (score 3):

We are confident to have pinned down the cause of this defect to a resource leak in the .NET framework 4.0.

Installations of our server application running on .NET 4.0 (clr.dll: 4.0.30319.1) show the intermittent COM runtime breakdown and are easily fixed by updating the .NET framework to version 4.5.1 (clr.dll: 4.0.30319.18444)

Here's how we identified the cause:

Searches on the web turned up an entry in an MSDN forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/f928f3cc-8a06-48be-9ed6-e3772bcc32e8/windows-7-x64-com-server-ole32dll-threads-are-not-cleaned-up-after-they-end-causing-com-client?forum=vcmfcatl

The OP there described receiving the HRESULT RPC_X_BAD_STUB_DATA (0x800706f7) from CoCreateInstanceEx(CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER) after running a COM server with an interop app for some length of time (a month or so). He tracked the issue down to a thread resource leak that was observable indirectly via an incrementing variable inside ole32.dll : EventPoolEntry::s_initState that causes CCI to fail once its value becomes 0xbfff...

An inspection of EventPoolEntry::s_initState in our faulty installations revealed that its value started out at approx. 0x8000 after a restart and then constantly gained between 100 and 200+ per hour with the app running under normal load. As soon as s_initState hit 0xbfff, the app failed with all the symptoms described in our original question. The OP in the MSDN forum suspected a COM thread-local resource leak as he observed asymmetrical calls to thread initialization and thread cleanup - 5 x init vs. 3 x cleanup.

By automatically tracing the value of s_initState over the course of several days we were able to demonstrate that updating the .NET framework to 4.5.1 from the original 4.0 completely eliminates the leak.